# Windows10, Com port numbering, two devices using the same number

Tags: com-port

I use a MicroHam DigiKeyer II in my system and this creates virtual serial ports so I can use multiple Communications programs (amateur radio).  The DigiKeyer works fine on it's own, but I have found that if I plug in another USB device that also needs a com port, (like a device which uses an FTDI RS232 converter), the Windows system allocates the new device Com7, but that is already in use as a virtual port by the DigiKeyer. I thought Windows10 should allocate an unused port, but it doesn't seem to.

I have tried going into Device Manager, Properties, Advanced, and changing the Com Port number for the new device from 7 to a number not being used by the DigiKeyer, but the DigiKeyer still will not work - message I get is "Com port already in use".  This is the case even after a reboot, and the only way I have found to get back to "normal" is to unplug the new device and uninstall it from Device Manager.

So, I need some advice on how best to be able to use the new device without upsetting my DigiKeyer virtual ports.  Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the DigiKeyer driver to me.  Looking at their documentation, I would remove all traces of digikeyer, add the other usb device that needs a com port.  Then re-add the digikeyer using another port as indicated on page 9 of [this manual](https://www.wimo.com/media/manuals/MICROHAM/Digi-Keyer_Digi-Keyer-v1_01.pdf).  I am just guessing but I assume it will work.  I am guessing this because this text tells me there is a bug in the way they are forcing the virtual port "DO NOT define a port that is already in use (for example, COM1 or COM2.. etc

Comment: Why would they allow that in the first place and put it on the user to make sure not to make a mistake?  This driver is half cooked.  Cool product.. just not fully cooked.

Comment: The [DIGI KEYER manual](https://www.wimo.com/media/manuals/MICROHAM/Digi-Keyer_Digi-Keyer-v1_01.pdf) says on page 15 that you may use port numbers that are much higher than COM7 and are not obliged to use the default t COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7. From the picture I guess that the limit may be COM32, but I don't have installed the microHAM USB Device Router software. Does this help?